# jQuery - Append value to the div inside confirmation box

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append the jQuery load result into the div which has the **class="output" inside the confirm dialog**. But due to some reasons, the result is not displaying in the confirm dialog where as when I try to paste the same div with class name output inside the form the result is printing. The print result is already written in cust_config_list function.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
select: function (event, ui) {
     function adddetails(data){
        var url='<?=base_url()?>index.php/Inquiry/cust_config_list';
        $(".output").load(url,{"config": data});
    }
    adddetails(ui.item.label);
     confirmDialog('Confirm', '<b>Below are the configuration types:</b><br><br><div class="output"></div>', function () {               

            });

     return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening. and in place of `$(".output").load(...)` just add some hard coded HTML for demo purpose.

Comment: You're literally doing nothing with the response from the `.load()`.  `...load(url, {"config":data}, function(response, status) { /* do something with response here */  });`

Comment: @Tibrogargan I just want to display the result in the <div class="output"></div> inside the confirm dialog. Modified the load method too

Comment: @Tibrogargan The print result is already written inside cust_config_list function. So no need to get the response inside the load.

Comment: Thanks for removing the extraneous callback.  You're calling some web server (code not shown) that returns some HTML (not shown) that is supposed to modify your web page (not shown) and it's not working.  There could be a bunch of reasons for this (not shown)